# Confusion in finding the derivative of $~\sec^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I was reading about differentiation of inverse trigonometrical functions and I've a confusion in the differentiation of $~\sec^{-1}(x)$.

The book says:

Let $f(x)=\sec^{-1}(x)=y$
which implies  $\cos^{-1} {1\over x}=y$

then they start to differentiate $~y~$ w.r.t $~x~$:
which implies

$-1\over\sqrt{((1-(1/x))^2~}~$ .$d\over dx$ $1\over x$

Now I understand that chain rule is being used here but I don't understand from where
$-1\over\sqrt{((1-(1/x))^2~}$

is coming from.

Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice:
$$arc\sec(x)=y\to \sec y =x\to\cos y=\frac1x\to y=\arccos(\frac 1x)$$
Then:
$$\arccos(p)=q \to p=\cos q\implies \frac{dp}{dq}=\sin q=\pm\sqrt{1-p^2}$$
from $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha\equiv1$

Hence:

$$\frac{dq}{dp}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}=\arccos'(p)$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\arccos'(x)=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, it follows from the chain rule that, if you differentiate $\arccos\left(\frac1x\right)$, what you will get is$$-\frac1{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac1x\right)^2}}\times\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac1x.$$

Comment: but we dont know arccos'(x), that is what we were finding, then how did it came this?

Comment: From the equation $y = \arccos x$, take the implicit derivative of both sides and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. You can use the identity $\sin(\arccos x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ by drawing a right triangle.

Comment: @MadDawg No. What you *are* trying to find here is $\operatorname{arcsec}'(x)$. Whoever wrote what you were reading clearly assumed that the readers knew that $\arccos'(x)=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

They are using the formula $$ \frac {d}{dx}\arccos (u ) =\frac {-1}{\sqrt {1-u^2} }\frac {du}{dx}.$$

In your question $$ u =\frac {1}{x}$$

Comment: You can write $\arccos u$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer